# Javascript Dictionary is returning both a value and "undefined"

Tags: javascript

I was trying to solve a problem where I would iterate through a dictionary, returning the corresponding values. This is my code.

```
var dict = {"Cost":"16","Description":"dkjfdkljskjf"};
var keys = Object.keys(dict);
console.log(keys)
for(var i = 0;i < keys.length;i++){
  console.log(dict[keys[i]]);
}
```

When this code ran, it returned the following:
[image]

Even though it returns the values, it also returns an undefined. What returns the undefined?What does it mean?Why is it returning both?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Javascript has no dictionaries. What you have there is an object. Use `Object.keys`, `Object.values`, and `Object.entries` to iterate through an object. Your `undefined` is not coming from your code, but from your entering of the code into the console manually; `console.log` returns `undefined`, and the console automatically prints the return value of the last statement (I think).

Comment: Cause you ran the code in some kind of REPL, and as you have no `return` in there, the list of statwments youve provided does evaluate to nothing

Comment: Because after evaluating the code in the REPL, nothing is returned from the last line...

Comment: Use console.log some more to see what is going on. console.log(”key:” +keys[i] + ”, value: ” + dict[keys[i]]);

Comment: The undefined printed in green is your function’s return value. In your case you are not returning anything, so it is undefined.

Comment: By the way, for iterating over an objects keys: the [`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop.

Comment: @Lucas No, don't do that, that requires the `hasOwnProperty` check. `Object.keys` is far superior in most cases.